# How to truncate entire string if it will overrun the max character count?

Tags: php

I need to limit this string to max 320 characters but also make it truncate cleanly if it is going to overrun e.g

I want

```
Testing Item 1 | Testing Item 2 | Testing Item 3
```

Instead of

```
Testing Item 1 | Testing Item 2 | Testing Item 3 | Tes
```

Currently I have this function:

```
/**
     * First filter out any empty values, strip any tags, then join each array item with a pipe | and limit it to 320 characters.
     * @param $array
     * @return string
     */
    public function limitStripAndJoin($array) {
        // Removes any empty strings from the array e.g if there's no caption on an image, we want to remove the empty string
        $filteredArray = array_filter($array, 'strlen');

        return strip_tags(substr(join(" | ", $filteredArray), 0, 320));
    }
```

I just need to know how stop going to the next item if it will overrun?

Comment: Just for fun, the following is a single "character" that is comprised of a 4-byte UTF8 sequence: ﷽

Comment: @ifusion specific to your case, I might use: https://3v4l.org/PW394